# Rendering multiple sprites from a single OpenGL ES texture

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I'm new to OpenGL ES 1.1 and am trying to start slowly by creating a set of functions that will render multiple sprites from a single texture on my iPhone. I have things working as I would expect them to (but please let me know if I'm making any obvious mistakes), but am now looking to optimise my code. As such, I have two questions:

1) How can I speed up the code below? As I understand it, I should be able to batch multiple draw calls from the same OpenGL texture to speed up rendering. How can I go about doing this, are there any good code examples I should be aware of?

2) Using glOrthof I've changed my coordinate system to run from 0, 0 to my device width and height. Is there a similar way of handling things when passing glTexCoordPointer texture coordinates that would allow me to pass in pixel values?

For reference, here is my code:

```
- (void)drawGLView
{
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);

    glClearColor( 0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, spriteTexture);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    for(Sprite *sprite in self.sprites)
    {
        [self drawAtPoint:sprite.location];
    }
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
    [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
}

- (void)drawAtPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    GLfloat x = point.x, y = point.y;
    GLfloat w = self.spritesheet.size.width;
    GLfloat h = self.spritesheet.size.height;
    GLfloat box[] = {
        x, y + h, 0,
        x, y, 0,
        x + w, y + h, 0,
        x + w, y , 0
    };
    GLfloat tex[] = {
        0, 1,
        0, 0,
        1, 1,
        1, 0
    };

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, box);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, tex);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Here is what i am using for my particle system(its in c++ , but u will get the point).You can put you textures in a row(horizontal , and all with the same size),and draw it with the correct id, 0-first tex , 1-second and so on;

```
class gltAtlasRenderer
{
public:
    float* partVdata;
    float* partCdata;
    float* partTdata;

    int counter1,counter2,counter3;
    int count;
    bool isz;
    int tilesize;
    float tilesx;
    gltAtlasRenderer(int maxTextures,bool iszi,int numberoftiles)
    {
        isz=iszi;
        if(isz)partVdata=(float*)malloc(maxTextures*18*4);
        else partVdata=(float*)malloc(maxTextures*12*4);

        partCdata=(float*)malloc(maxTextures*24*4);
        partTdata=(float*)malloc(maxTextures*12*4);
        tilesize=numberoftiles;
        tilesx=(float)(1.0f/numberoftiles);
    }
    void Draw(int id,float x,float y,float z,float scalex,float scaley,float angle,float r,float g,float b,float a)
    {
        angle*=0.017453f;
        for(int c2=0;c2<12;c2+=2)
        {
                float x=squarevData[c2]*scalex;
                float y=squarevData[c2+1]*scaley;
                float cos1=cos(angle);
                float sin1=sin(angle);
                squarevData2[c2] = (cos1*x) - ( sin1*y);
                squarevData2[c2+1] = (sin1*x) + ( cos1*y);
        }


        //up left
        partVdata[counter1++]=x+squarevData2[0];
        partVdata[counter1++]=y+squarevData2[1];
        if(isz)partVdata[counter1++]=z;
        partCdata[counter2++]=r;
        partCdata[counter2++]=g;
        partCdata[counter2++]=b;
        partCdata[counter2++]=a;
        partTdata[counter3++]=tilesx*id;
        partTdata[counter3++]=1;

        //up right
        partVdata[counter1++]=x+squarevData2[2];
        partVdata[counter1++]=y+squarevData2[3];
        if(isz)partVdata[counter1++]=z;
        partCdata[counter2++]=r;
        partCdata[counter2++]=g;
        partCdata[counter2++]=b;
        partCdata[counter2++]=a;
        partTdata[counter3++]=tilesx*id+tilesx;
        partTdata[counter3++]=1;


        //down left
        partVdata[counter1++]=x+squarevData2[4];
        partVdata[counter1++]=y+squarevData2[5];
        if(isz)partVdata[counter1++]=z;
        partCdata[counter2++]=r;
        partCdata[counter2++]=g;
        partCdata[counter2++]=b;
        partCdata[counter2++]=a;
        partTdata[counter3++]=tilesx*id;
        partTdata[counter3++]=0;

        //up right
        partVdata[counter1++]=x+squarevData2[6];
        partVdata[counter1++]=y+squarevData2[7];
        if(isz)partVdata[counter1++]=z;
        partCdata[counter2++]=r;
        partCdata[counter2++]=g;
        partCdata[counter2++]=b;
        partCdata[counter2++]=a;
        partTdata[counter3++]=tilesx*id+tilesx;
        partTdata[counter3++]=1;

        //down right
        partVdata[counter1++]=x+squarevData2[8];
        partVdata[counter1++]=y+squarevData2[9];
        if(isz)partVdata[counter1++]=z;
        partCdata[counter2++]=r;
        partCdata[counter2++]=g;
        partCdata[counter2++]=b;
        partCdata[counter2++]=a;
        partTdata[counter3++]=tilesx*id+tilesx;
        partTdata[counter3++]=0;


        //down left
        partVdata[counter1++]=x+squarevData2[10];
        partVdata[counter1++]=y+squarevData2[11];
        if(isz)partVdata[counter1++]=z;
        partCdata[counter2++]=r;
        partCdata[counter2++]=g;
        partCdata[counter2++]=b;
        partCdata[counter2++]=a;
        partTdata[counter3++]=tilesx*id;
        partTdata[counter3++]=0;

        count++;

    }
    void RenderStart()
    {
        counter1=counter2=count=counter3=0;

    }
    void RenderStop(int textureid)
    {
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_MODULATE);
        glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureid);
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, partTdata);
        glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0,partCdata );
        if(isz)glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, partVdata);
        else glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, partVdata);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, count*6);
        glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    }
};

gltAtlasRenderer ar=new gltAtlasRenderer(100,false,5);//max textures, is there z,max textures in texture
ar.RenderStart();
void Render()
{
     for(int c=0;c<100;c++)ar.Draw(0,x,y,z,scalex,scaley,rotation,r,g,b,a);
}
ar.RenderStop(textureid);
```

2)If i understand correct you want to use texture cordinates with the size of the texture(instead of a scale of 0 to 1)

For example in a texture 512x512 the texture cordinates will be

```
float cv(float maxsize,float num)
{
     return (num/maxsize);
}

cv(0),cv(0)//bot,left
cv(512),cv(0)//bot,right
cv(512),cv(512)//top,right
cv(0),cv(512)//bot,left
```